# POST request not working with JSON on POSTMAN

Tags: node.js, express, backend

so I just began to learn some back end work, and I learned POSTMAN is a great tool for testing HTTP request methods. I have POSTMAN installed on my windows PC. I am running into a problem, in which whenever I want to test out POST method for creating an item, I just see "sending request" on POSTMAN without having a result.

My codes are the following,

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const contacts = [{id:4}];
const contact_id = 1

const PORT = 3000;

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send(`welcome to ${contacts}`)
})

app.post('/hello',(req,res)=>{
    const contact = {
        id:contact_id+1
    }
    contacts.push(contact);
})

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log(`Server started on ${PORT}`)
})
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You need to send a [response](https://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res) to your client (here: Postman), like `res.json(contacts);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `pzaenger` correctly pointed out, you are never closing the connection on the server end with a `res.end()`, `res.send()` or `res.json()`.

You need to close the connection with one of these methods, so that POSTMAN will receive your server's data (result):

```js
app.post('/hello',(req,res)=>{
    const contact = {
        id: contact_id+1
    }
    contacts.push( contact );
    res.json( contacts );
});
```